# Bluez C RFCOMM Bluetooth server getting no route to host

Tags: c, bluetooth, rfcomm

I am using the code at the following link:
http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x502.html

I run the server, and when I run the client with my mac address (server listens on port 0x1001 , this is where the client connects), I get no roue to host. I have replaced the MAC addresses with my MAC address of my bluetooth device.

If I put in a bogus MAC, it takes longer and times out, so it is at least behaving differently for my real MAC address. I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and can communicate with my Phone via GNOME, so I know the functionality works.

Comment: are you trying to run client and server on the same machine with single BD MAC address?

Comment: The same thing also happens with L2CAP.

Comment: Yes, I am. They are both running on my machine locally.

Comment: You can't use a single device as server and client.  You can add a USB bluetooth dongle to give yourself a second device if you want to do local testing.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618277/rfcomm-without-pairing-using-pybluez-on-debian