# connect android and linux via bluetooth

Tags: android, linux, bluetooth, rfcomm

I have made an app android which need to connect to linux system embedded that use rfcomm to connect with the app via bluetooth. More specifically the appa andorid is the Server bluetooth and the embedded linux is the client. I have tried to connect they them but when I exec rfcomm connect rfcomm0, the result is connection refused. my rfcomm.conf file is
and I have used sdptool browser to know the channel.

> ## RFCOMM configuration file.
>
> #
>
> rfcomm0{
>     # Automatically bind the device at startup
>     bind no;

```
># Bluetooth address of the device
>device     00:18:30:9C:32:E3;

># RFCOMM channel for the connection
>channel    6;
```

> # Description of the connection
>     comment "Example Bluetooth device";
>   }

but when i exec rfcomm connect rfcomm0 the result is
connection refused

any suggest?

Comment: this might help :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17216264/bluetooth-connection-between-android-and-linux-rpi-lost-on-first-write-action