# How to connect pybluez RFCOMM server socket on Debian?

Tags: android, python, bluetooth, debian, bluez

I have these snippet in python with pybluez framework:

```
from bluetooth import *

server_sock=BluetoothSocket( RFCOMM )
server_sock.bind(("",PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)

port = server_sock.getsockname()[1]

uuid = "94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"

advertise_service( server_sock, "SampleServer",
                   service_id = uuid
                   # service_classes = [ uuid, SERIAL_PORT_CLASS ],
                   # profiles = [ SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE ],
                   # protocols = [ RFCOMM_UUID ]
                    )

print "Waiting for connection on RFCOMM channel %d" % port

client_sock, client_info = server_sock.accept()
print "Accepted connection from ", client_info

try:
    while True:
        data = client_sock.recv(1024)
        if len(data) == 0: break
        print "received [%s]" % data
except IOError:
    pass

print "disconnected"

client_sock.close()
server_sock.close()
print "all done"
```

and also I have this other snippet in Android to connect the pybluez rfcomm server socket:

```
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"); 
....
BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(myServerMacAddress);
....
BluetoothSocket tmp= device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
```

My problem is that Android device could not connect to the pybluez socket.
I think that the way I use to connect is wrong, and I don't know how to connect correctly or advertise my server socket

Answer (score 4):

I offered a bounty, but found the solution myself. :) Posted on another answer but this may also apply to your problem. On certain versions of Debian (Raspbian etc) and maybe some others distros. The `server_sock.accept()` will by default just hang and never accept a connection - even from a paired device! I'm in some cases even convinced the socket isn't  open at all. However, a solution to this is really simple.

Update your */etc/bluetooth/main.conf* file, add a line or change the existing so it looks like this:

```
DisablePlugins = pnat
```

Then restart the Bluetooth service:

```
sudo invoke –rc.d bluetooth restart
```

It now MAY have been fixed.

Good luck!

Reference: [RFCOMM without pairing using PyBluez on Debian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618277/rfcomm-without-pairing-using-pybluez-on-debian/14827036#14827036)

Comment: Into which section does the setting belong? Is the second command identical to `sudo service bluetooth restart`?