# connection between android and linux over bluetooth

Tags: android, linux, bluetooth, cross-platform, bluez

I wrote the android application for bluetoothchat program and it worked perfectly between two individual android devices.

However, the problem is that I don't know how to build up some specific program for allowing the connection between Linux(Ubuntu 14.04) and android.
The application for android is basically using the sample code Google provides, which uses the UUID, bluetooth socket, insecure serial communication.

Here, what am I going to do with making these connection possible?
I googled some possible answers, for example using PyBlueZ, but does it really work for my problem? I mean, the language for android is basically on Java and PyBlueZ is literally on Python, so is there any conflict?

What could be the best and simplest answer for my problem?

Comment: I found the url, similar problem I concerned. Is it helpful for mine?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399146/how-to-connect-pybluez-rfcomm-server-socket-in-android

Comment: pybluez should work just fine.