# Python Bluetooth Error on Raspberry Pi 3 (Server)

Tags: android, python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, rfcomm

```
Listening for connections on port:  0  
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "server.py", line 29, in <module>
    runServer()       
  File "server.py", line 19, in runServer
    profiles = [ bluetooth.SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE ]      
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bluetooth/bluez.py", line 176, in advertise_service
    raise BluetoothError (str (e)) 
bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (2, 'No such file or directory')
```

This is the Error that I am getting when I run the following Script on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B.

```
import bluetooth

name="bt_server"
target_name="siggen"
uuid="222705e1-e1e6-47f5-aa92-1c5ae849f3f1"

def runServer():
    serverSocket=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
    port=bluetooth.PORT_ANY
    serverSocket.bind(("",port))
    print "Listening for connections on port: ", port   
    serverSocket.listen(1)
    port=serverSocket.getsockname()[1]

    #the missing piece
    bluetooth.advertise_service( serverSocket, "SampleServer",
                       service_id = uuid,
                       service_classes = [ uuid, bluetooth.SERIAL_PORT_CLASS ],
                       profiles = [ bluetooth.SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE ] 
                        )

    inputSocket, address=serverSocket.accept()
    print "Got connection with" , address
    data=inputSocket.recv("1024")
    print "received [%s] \n " % data    
    inputSocket.close()
    serverSocket.close()  

runServer()
```

I have bluez version 5.37. I have followed these links ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36375064/cannot-run-python-bluez-rfcomm-server-example-script)) and ([link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618277/rfcomm-without-pairing-using-pybluez-on-debian/14827036#14827036)). They don't seem to solve the problem.

I can connect my android to raspberry pi using following terminal commands

> sdptool add sp

It does not give any response.

> sudo rfcomm listen hci0&

The device is connected (using blueterm app)

> cat /dev/rfcomm0

This port is used to receive the data

Also, the following script works

```
import bluetooth

server_sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )

port = 1
server_sock.bind(("",port))
server_sock.listen(1)

client_sock,address = server_sock.accept()
print("Accepted connection from ",address)

data = client_sock.recv(1024)
print("received [%s]" % data)

client_sock.close()
server_sock.close()
```

Hence the bluetooth is totally functional. The only problem that I have is of profiles. I can't figure out what the problem is. Any sort of help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: try this.
May be you don't have all the required resources.
[Running Server Script on Raspberry Pi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36375064/cannot-run-python-bluez-rfcomm-server-example-script?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You need install libbluetooth-dev, just like the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libbluetooth-dev
```